# Which Swing layout can be used to develop the following GUI design?

Tags: java, swing

Being a newbie in Swing, I am not sure which layout to use for designing the following design. Please suggest me.
I tried using GridLayout, but it divides the frame in equal parts which messes the button area. I read about using GridBagLayout, but being totally new in Swing, I am not sure if it will work. Since I have lot on my plate to work on this project and very less time, I do not want to waste time. So looking for a easy and assured solution.
Please suggest me an easy solution for this.

Design: Has two editors on the upper part of the frame (each occupying half width of the frame). Following it will a single button in the center. Following the button will be two scroll able tables (each occupying half of the frame width).

Edit: Thank you all. So I started with GridBagLayout and I am close to what I want. The only problem is I want the 2nd row to have only a submit button but due to some reason my submit button gets embedded in to the scrollable tables in the 3rd row. Basically the 2nd row does not appear at at all. Following is the code I have written. Please suggest me the corrections.

class SplitPane extends JFrame  {

```
private static JPanel panel2;
private static JPanel panel5;
private static JScrollPane panel3;
private static JScrollPane panel4;
protected JSplitPane split;

public SplitPane(JChemPaintPanel p){

    JFrame f = new JFrame("");
    //f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 10, 10 ));
     f.addWindowListener(new JChemPaintPanel.AppCloser());
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    //f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();


    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=0.3;
    c.weighty=0.3;
    p.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
    p.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    pane.add(p, c);

    c.gridx=1;
    c.gridy=0;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=0.3;
    c.weighty=0.3;
    pane.add(createPanel2(), c);


    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;
    c.gridheight=2;
    c.gridwidth=0;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    //c.weightx=0.3;
    //c.weighty=0.3;
    pane.add(createPanel5(), c);


    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=2;
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.gridwidth=1;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=0.3;
    c.weighty=0.3;
    pane.add(createPanel3(), c);


    c.gridx=1;
    c.gridy=2;
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.gridwidth=1;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx=0.3;
    c.weighty=0.3;
    pane.add(createPanel4(), c);

    f.add(pane);
    f.pack();
    Point point = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint();

    int w2 = 1000;
    int h2 = 1000;
    f.setLocation(point.x - w2, point.y - h2);
    f.setVisible(true);

}
//top right
public static JPanel createPanel2(){
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    panel2.add((new TextArea("Panel2")));
    panel2.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
    panel2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    return panel2;
}

public static JPanel createPanel5(){
    panel5 = new JPanel();
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Submit");
    panel5.add(b1);

    return panel5;
}


//bottom left
public static JScrollPane createPanel3(){
    Label label_prop = new Label("Properties:", Label.LEFT);
    String[] columnNames = {"Properties","",};
    Object[][] data = {
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
            {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""} 
            };


    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table.setRowHeight(20);
    table.setBorder(BasicBorders.getMenuBarBorder());

    panel3 = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel3.add(new JButton("Submit"));
    panel3.add(label_prop);
    panel3.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 5, 5 ) );
    panel3.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 5, 5 ) );
    return panel3;


}
//bottom right
public static JScrollPane createPanel4(){

    panel4 = new JScrollPane();
    String[] columnNames = {"Activities","",};
    Object[][] data = {
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""},
                {"", "",}, {"", ""}, {"", ""},{"", ""} 
                };


    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table.setRowHeight(20);
    table.setBorder(BasicBorders.getMenuBarBorder());
    panel4 = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel4.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 5, 5 ) );
    panel4.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 5, 5 ) );
    return panel4;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add an image to be more descriptive in the layout that you are requiring?

Comment: GridBagLayout would work. You could also divide your GUI into sections (using panels), then give each panel it's own layout

Comment: I cannot upload an image as I am not having 10 reputation.

Comment: @Vince I think GridBagLayout will work in my case. But it seems to be very complicated to develop. Any link for easy study of GridBagLayout will help. Thanks

Comment: GridBagLayout is the most flexible layout manager.  Once you learn it the sky is the limit.  I'd go with that.

Comment: Thank you all. So I started with GridBagLayout and I am close to get what I want.

Comment: The Netbeans Visual Gui Builder is a nice tool for quickly throwing together a Gui.
It makes it really easy to drag and drop components and resize things.  If you are new to Swing its a nice place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), there are example GUIs that use layout managers and tells you where to find the how-to page for each layout manager. It's very helpful.

Comment: Thanks I will go through this